# How do I dynamically add elements to arrays in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, function, dynamic, powershell

I don't have much PowerShell experience yet and am trying to teach myself as I go along.

I'm trying to make some proof of concept code for a bigger project. The main goal here is too dynamically create and add elements to an array using a function.

Here is my code:

```
$testArray = @()
function addToArray($Item1)
{
    $testArray += $Item1
    "###"
}

$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"
$foldertest = "testFolder"

foreach($item in $tempArray)
{
    addToArray $item
}
"###"
```

Every time the function finishes the array becomes empty.
Bear in mind most of my programming experience comes from Java, PHP, some C and C++ just to name a few, if I did this in PHP (adjusting the language syntax of course) this would have worked fine.

Comment: Why not use a list instead? Arrays were never meant to be operated dynamically. Every time you resize an array, it creates a new one under the hood. So you get the overhead proportional to its size.

Comment: thanks for the advice neolisk, i did think of that, i'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$testArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"

foreach($item in $tempArray)
{
    $arrayID = $testArray.Add($item)
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The problem is one of scope; inside your addToArray function change the line to this:

```
$script:testArray += $Item1
```

...to store into the array variable you are expecting.

Comment: Note that the drawback of this method is that it creates an in-memory copy of the entire existing array with the new item in it.  In other words, it's O( 2n ) memory usage.  If you're doing this a lot or with very large arrays, it becomes very expensive.  Using an ArrayList reuses the same object and adds the item to it directly.

Comment: Quite so, @BaconBits; thanks for adding that important caveat when dealing with larger arrays.

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** If you want to have **dynamic** (non-fixed) amount of items, a more precise solution might be using the `List`:

```
$testArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"

foreach($item in $tempArray)
{
    $testArray.Add($item)
}
```

Note: In this case you get the power of the List from **.Net**, so you can easily apply linq, merge, split, and do anything which you'd do with the List in .Net

Answer (score 2):

Instead of re-creating the array in each loop iteration (which is basically what's happening each time you add to it), assign the result of the the loop to a variable:

```
$testArray = foreach($item in $tempArray)
{
    addToArray $item
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice i may try that next time i go to make a complex script

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an item at the beginning of an array (as index 0), this may work, like array_unshift($array, $item) on PHP:

```
$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"
$foldertest = "testFolder"
$tempArray = @($foldertest) + $tempArray
```

This gives:

```
PS D:\users\user1\temp> $temparray
testFolder
123
321
453
```

Comment: It's a PowerShell question, not PHP. PHP arrays are significantly different to PowerShell arrays since PowerShell arrays are a fixed length. To "add" to a PowerShell array, under the hood it basically creates a new array with the new length and copies every element to it. I believe in PHP they are dynamic (more like a PowerShell Generic list). You may want to consider removing your answer to avoid confusing readers